# clickable options in Dialgflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

Is it possible to show **clickable options** in **Dialogflow CX**? If "YES" can I get an example for this.

I have created a simple Agent in Dialogflow CX. When the user enters a city name then I want to list pin codes that should be **clickable**. How can I achieve this in **Dialogflow CX**?

Comment: Additional to the previous response; if you are using an external application to communicate with Dialogflow CX, you could just provide buttons on the front-end with the options; then send the text selected as input which will match to your pre-set intents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this by means of the "Custom Payload" option in the fulfillment section of a page.
You first need to access a page which allows a fulfilmment, then you click on [image: edit fulfillment]

Once in the window of the fulfillment you may select *add dialog option* and then *custom payload* [image: like so]

Finally, you can use Google's documentation to build your custom payload of type "button" and paste the code in here. [This is a link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#button_response_type) to the documentation section I'm referring to.

On a final note, please try to solve the problem by yourself: it is the second question of yours I answer on this topic, and in both cases a simple Google Search provided all the information needed.